# como agregar textos largos en una Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

mi consulta es la siguiente debo incorporar en una Activity de android el siguiente textos, no se como implementarlo con ese estilo, dejo imagen del texto a colocar:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques el código de lo que has trabajado. Revisa [ask]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "ese estilo"? ¿Letra? ¿Color? ¿Salto de línea? ¿Font?

Comment: La consulta es la siguiente como debo crear textos largos como muestra la imagen con partes en color rojo otras en negrita resaltado y otras en negro sin resaltar;

Answer (score 1):

Puede hacer que su TextView sea desplazable y multilínea para lograr esto:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/receipt"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:textSize="15dp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:text=""/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar de varias formas, no es necesario crear varios TextViews con diferentes estilos. Puedes usar sólo uno y si tienes conocimientos básicos de html puedes usar [.fromHtml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview) otro ejemplo [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview).

Además puedes usar html desde [strings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38272292/15298643)